# Cmake complains " -- The C compiler identification is unknown -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown"

Tags: c++, cmake

During source file configuration with cmake , it shows

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown**
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- broken
CMake Error at /home/pranto/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/usr/bin/cc"
```

I see couple of question's answer but nothing works for solving my problem.

- Cmake version:  3.12.0
- gcc :  7.4.0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider reviewing the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Your question is lacking several details so it is hard to understand what is going on. Please provide a description of what you are trying to accomplish, the commands you ran to produce this error, and any other contextual information about the problem, such as prior software installations or environment variable settings.

Comment: Try building outside the source directory if you are not doing it already. Also try to do a clean build to see if the problem disapear.

Comment: Make sure that `/usr/bin/cc` works first.

Comment: `gcc : 7.4.0` - how did you check that?

Comment: The CMake error should have pointed to a logfile. Post that too.

Comment: You cut CMake output after the line with the compiler's path, but exactly the rest of the output is very **important** for understanding the problem. Without viewing the rest of output we cannot help you.

Comment: I already solve the problem. Thanks for your help

Comment: If you solved your problem, it's good etiquette to post the solution you found as an answer and mark it as accepted.